# Altering Venus rotational speed to match Earth's via weather manipulation

Tags: rotational-dynamics, atmospheric-science, weather, planets

Venus rotates approximately 6.5 km an hour Earth rotates approximately 1650 km/h how fast could we speed up Venus's rotation via only weather manipulation ( maybe    a giant fractal lens between Venus and the Sun at a gravitationally equilibrium point, the lens redirecting all the energy hitting Venus shifting it so as to heat one portion, while shadowing the others, in such a way to create a belt of  wind circling the equator) there was a Report recently showing the alteration of the planet Venus rotational Time. http://www.esa.int/esaSC/SEM0TLSXXXG_index_0.html at 90 PSI density atmosphere that much energy available, how long would it take for the frictional energy of the atmosphere to speed up the rotation of Venus  to the Earth equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using data from [here](http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/venusfact.html), increasing Venus' rotational speed to match Earth's would require about $\:\mathrm{1.5\times 10^{29}\ J}$.

It's insolation is about $\:\mathrm{3\times 10^{17}\ W}$, so assuming that somehow all this energy could be transferred to rotation, it would take about 16000 years - not absurdly long actually.